# Card Magic Trick, algorith that orders cards

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I've been working on this question for quite some time now, the question is below:

Consider the following “magic” trick. You have a deck of n cards, labeled 1,2,...,n (but not necessarily in that order).
You then repeat the following process until no cards are left:

- Show to the public the card on the top of the deck, and remove it from the deck
- Take the next card from the top of the deck and place it at the bottom of the deck, without showing it.

Your goal is to have previously ordered the cards in the deck so that the cards shown to the public are in increasing order: 1, 2, ...,n.

For example:
 if n=5, then starting from the arrangement 1,5,2,4,3 would work:
1,5,2,4,3 -> 2,4,3,5 -> 3,5,4 -> 4,5 ->  5

Question: Write an algorithm that prints the appropriate initial ordering for any given number n of cards.

Algorithm orderCards(n)
Input: An integer n
Output : Prints the correct card ordering.

I managed to get the following:

```
n=1 --> 1
n=2 --> 1,2
n=3 --> 1,3,2
n=4 --> 1,3,2,4
n=5 --> 1,5,2,4,3
n=6 --> 1,4,2,6,3,5
n=7 --> 1,6,2,5,3,7,4
n=8 --> 1,5,2,7,3,6,4,8
```

As you can see there is a pattern in every other number such that 1,x,2,x,4,x...
I also believe that the algorithm will be different depending on if your n value is even or odd, but I'm not too sure how. If n is even the second element = value(n-2)  + 1

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The Wall of Text (TM) approach to asking questions rarely garners useful responses. If a paragraph is longer than 3 lines long, it's next to impossible to read. I, for one, don't bother...

Answer (score 2):

Never obey the "play" rules when it comes to magic (or writing generators based on reductions, or reducers based on generation rules): you know the final ordering you want, so generate the start sequence by running the trick in reverse. Treat all cards as visible, put the last card on top of the "empty" deck, move it from the bottom to the top (this doesn't change the order for the last card of course) and then put the next card on top. Repeat until done.

So, let's start with the final order you want to "end up with". Say, `1,2,3,4,5`. Then:

```
1,2,3,4,5, put last visible on top of the deck
→ 1,2,3,4 + 5. Then move bottom to top, add last visible card:
→ 1,2,3 + 4,5. Then move bottom to top, add last visible card:
→ 1,2 + 3,(4,5 → 5,4) = 3,5,4. Then move bottom to top, add last visible card:
→ 1 + 2,(3,5,4 → 4,3,5) = 2,4,3,5. Then move bottom to top, add last visible card:
→ 1,(2,4,3,5 → 5,2,4,3) = 1,5,2,4,3.
```

done.

If we run this for `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` we get `1,6,2,10,3,7,4,9,5,8`, in 10 steps.

Also notice that this algorithm is O(n): For a sequence of 1000 cards we perform 1000 "move bottom to top, then add card on top" steps. Can we improve on this? Possibly, but that requires looking at longer sequences to see if we can find the pattern in the permutations this generates.

We know it's extremely regular, so there probably are improvements to be made - for instance, with sequence `1,2,...,n-1,n` we can immediately fully determine the "odd" cards in the deck: `1,2,...,n/2` (in the 1..5 sequence, the numbers are `1,x,2,x,3`, and for `1..10` we see `1,x,2,x,3,x,4,x,5,x`). If we can figure out how the rest of the numbers fall into place, we'll probably be able to find an O(1) algorithm for immediately generating the deck sequence to start with. Slightly beyond the scope of this answer, though.

Comment: Did you make a mistake somewhere? 15432 produces cards in the order 14235.

Comment: yep, used "move top to bottom" instead of the "move bottom to top" as it should have been. updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with blank cards, and write the index on each (ie: the top one gets 0, the next 1, and so on). Perform the trick, and every time you show a card to the public, write on it the number you want them to see.

Here's code that does that. `cards` stores the original indexes of the cards, and gets manipulated like the rules of the trick. `values` stores the number written on each indexed card. After the trick is done, `values` stores the numbers for the trick to work.

This isn't Java, but here's the algorithm:

```
def order(n):
    cards = range(n)
    values = [None] * n
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        values[cards.pop(0)] = i
        if cards:
            cards.insert(len(cards)-1, cards.pop(0))
    return values

for n in xrange(1, 9):
    print 'n=%d --> %s' % (n, ','.join(map(str, order(n))))
```

Output:

```
n=1 --> 1
n=2 --> 1,2
n=3 --> 1,3,2
n=4 --> 1,3,2,4
n=5 --> 1,5,2,4,3
n=6 --> 1,4,2,6,3,5
n=7 --> 1,6,2,5,3,7,4
n=8 --> 1,5,2,7,3,6,4,8
```

The code is more magic than the original magic trick!